# Javascript : accessing function arguments generically

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

Here is what I have :

```
var log = function(arg1, arg2){
    console.log("inside :" + arg1 + " / " + arg2);
}; 

var wrap = function(fn){
    return function(args){ 
        console.log("before :");
        fn(args);
        console.log("after :");
    }
};

var fn = new wrap(log);
fn(1,2);
```

It is wrong, because I'd like to get in the console :

```
before :
inside :1 / 2
after :
```

But I get this instead :

```
before :
inside :1 / undefined
after :
```

How can I tell javascript that `args` is all the arguments passed to the function returned by `wrap` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Function/apply) to call a function with a specified 'this' and argument array, so try

```
var wrap = function(fn){
    return function(){ 
        console.log("before :");
        fn.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log("after :");
    }
};
```

Comment: Try fn.apply(this, arguments);

Comment: have made example more closely match what you are attempting