# Javascripts call function with parameters

Tags: javascript

example:

```
function MyDev() {
   this.someFunc;
   this.run = function() {
       if (typeof this.someFunc == 'function') {
          this.someFunc();
       } 
   }
}

var dev = new MyDev();
dev.someFunc = function(args1, args2,...) {
   //dosomething...
}
dev.run();
```

now, when call function dev.run(), how to call function abcdef with parameters? somebody can help me???

Comment: With what parameters? `run` is defined so as to call `someFunc` with no arguments.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript : accessing function arguments generically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006590/javascript-accessing-function-arguments-generically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript has a keyword called "arguments".
In a function, this is an array that contains all arguments passed to that function.

```
    function hehey(){
        console.log(arguments);
        // The console will show an array with ['hello', 'foo', 'bar', 'world']
    }
    hehey('hello', 'foo', 'bar', 'world');
```

So you can use this by just sending in the arguments keyword from the parent function like this:

```
function MyDev() {
    this.someFunc;
    this.run = function() {
        if (typeof this.someFunc == 'function') {
            this.someFunc(arguments);
        }
    }
}

var dev = new MyDev();
dev.someFunc = function(test, test2) {
    console.log(test, test2);
}
dev.run("hello", "world");
```

---

For more info on the `.apply` method: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/4zc42wh1(v=vs.94).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/4zc42wh1%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Comment: var args = ["toan", 23];
this.someFunc.apply(null, args); it working, but this.someFunc.apply(null, arguments); it not working because arguments allways is []; how to get arguments of function?

Comment: I have edited it to show an example. I have tested the code and it seems to work :)